# Every finite group is finitely generated. - alternate proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Is that's all? Thank you. :-)

> A group $H$ is called *finitely generated* if there is a finite set $A$ such that $H = \left \langle A \right \rangle$ . Prove that every finite group is finitely generated.

Because $\forall a \in A, a\in H$. Hence, if $A$ is infinite, $H$ is infinite. Hence every finite group is finitely generated.

Comment: You forgot to tell us that $H$ is a group and $A\subseteq H$ is a generating set. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66256/

Comment: The group elements are a set of generators. There are finitely many. Note that there are many *infinite* finitely generated groups. So if your post says that if a group is infinite, it is not finitely generated, then that part is not correct.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas - so as what I proved is correct, right?

Comment: Yes @JonasMeyer, I missed the definition. Thank you. So now I got the proof correctly?

Comment: There is a small missing step, which is that the group does have a set of generators. It is cleaner to write as in the first sentence of my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct: If there are infinitely many distinct generators, there are infinitely many distinct group elements.

For an alternative (simpler?) proof, just note that $H = \langle H \rangle$.